# Дату формата Y-n сравнить по 2-м полям в БД

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, blade

Есть таблица TOS_MES, в ней есть поля MONTH_CH и YEAR_CH, в шаблоне есть 2 поля input с type = 'month' (дата от и до) . Как вывести все данные из этой таблицы по датам которые указал пользователь в этих полях? Пытался сделать через whereBetween, однако он работает не корректно, а именно если я к примеру выберу 6-й месяц и 2017-й год и по 11-й месяц 2018-го, он выведет только данные с 6-11 месяцы. Пытался привести эти данные в Unix-время, но в таком случае вообще ничего не выводится. Дата в формате Y-n:

```
 $newDateFrom = explode("-", $data['dateFrom']); // Дата от
  $newDateTo = explode("-", $data['dateTo']); // Дата до
    $dataForTable = DB::table('CAT_STATION')
                            ->join('CAT_OBL', 'CAT_STATION.OBL_ID', '=', 'CAT_OBL.OBL_ID')
                            ->join('TOS_MES', 'CAT_STATION.IND_ST', '=', 'TOS_MES.IND_ST')
                            ->select('CAT_OBL.NAME_OBL', 'CAT_STATION.NAME_ST', 'TOS_MES.IND_ST', 'TOS_MES.YEAR_CH', 'TOS_MES.MONTH_CH', 'TOS_MES.T', 'TOS_MES.OS')
                            ->orderBy('CAT_STATION.OBL_ID', 'asc')
                            ->orderBy('CAT_STATION.IND_ST')
                            ->whereIn('CAT_STATION.OBL_ID', $data['regionName'])
                            ->whereBetween('YEAR_CH', [$newDateFrom[0], $newDateTo[0]])
                            ->whereBetween('MONTH_CH', [$newDateFrom[1], $newDateTo[1]])
                            ->get();
```

Comment: Соберите год и месяц фильтра как строки воедино по шаблону YYYYMM, и отбирайте обычным BETWEEN по аналогичному выражению из полей таблицы. *если я к примеру выберу 6-й месяц и 2017-й год и по 11-й месяц 2018-го*, то будете искать от 201706 до 201811.

Comment: Поле input и возвращает мне строку формата yyyy-MM и запрос работает, но не корректно ибо он тогда не выводит мне месяца до 6-го и после 11-го

Comment: А поля таблицы в тот же формат собраны?

Comment: Поля таблицы - int

Comment: O! ну так их же ж надо превратить в строковые, причём с ведущим нулём для месяца, и сконкатенировать в тот же формат, что поступает с фильтра. Или наоборот, превратить всё (и поля, и условие фильтра) в числа - не забыв умножить год на 12...

Comment: То есть мне надо взять 2 поля, привести их в 1 формат с фильтром и сделать конкатенацию? А как тогда будет выглядеть сам запрос в БД?)